# Sort Array of Objects by specific key value | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting a specific array of objects from a small personal project I'm working on. I have never had trouble using the Array.prototype.sort() function before, but I wonder if something about the multiple object keys is affecting it...

Been staring at it for longer than I care to admit and just need to ask for help now. :|

**Goal**: Sort array of objects alphabetically relative to a specific key.value on each of them.

Thanks in advance!

**[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nym26y6h/)**

Sort function example - (I recommend looking at the full Fiddle for context though).

```
var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => { return a.key > b.key; });
```

**SOLVED**

@Ryan helped me find that returned a boolean isn't enough, you need to explicitly return a positive or negative number, or 0.

@Brk showed me an awesome quick way to do it.

This post has a very detailed description. 
[Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)

Thanks all! Sorry for the duplicate post :|

Comment: The sort comparison function should return `-1` if `a < b`, `0` if `a = b`, or `1` if `a > b`.

Comment: I thought returning true / false would be good enough, it always has been before. But your comment inspired me to search again and I found this article... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Ok... So annoying. Thanks though!

Comment: @Ryan Note that it isn't required to return the specific values `1` or `-1`. Any positive or negative value is treated the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**localeCompare**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method  which will returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

```
var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.subreddit.localeCompare(b.subreddit)
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nym26y6h/1/)

Comment: This is awesome! 

Thanks!!

Comment: @TJBlackman thanks & happy to help

Comment: You are thopu boss